# firstChild node issue for DOM traversal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Building this basic to-do list from scratch to try and teach myself Javascript. I found out through the API that there is a firstChild function that will target the first child of a parent node.

If I have..

```
<div class = "parentNode">

  <div id = "i0">
   TEXT HERE
  </div>

  <div id = "i1">
  </div>

</div>
```

Then I have some button that is designated to the function:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {

   var parentNode = document.getElementById('parentNode');
   var childNode  = parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML;
   alert('childNode');

}
```

Why would this not return TEXT HERE in the alert box?

Comment: Note also that browsers differ in how they treat whitespace between elements. Some will convert them to empty text nodes, so the first child of *.parentNode* will be an empty text node (which does not have an innerHTML property), others will ignore the whitespace and the first child will be the div element *#i0*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. First, you are looking for an element that does not exist

```
var parentNode = document.getElementById('parentNode');
```

is looking for an id. This can be remedied by using an `id="parentNode` on the element, or you can query by class name instead using [`querySelector`<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

```
var parentNode = document.querySelector('.parentNode');
```

Next, `alert('childNode');` will always alert the string "`childNode`" and not the variable `childNode` so that needs to be `alert(childNode)`.

Lastly, and perhaps most interesting, is that `.firstChild` will get the first `childNode` of the set of childNodes. This can be a `#text` node (which it is), becuase of the whitespace used between the end of the `<div class = "parentNode">` and the beginning of `<div id = "i0">`.

As opposed to using `.firstChild`, you can use `children[0]` which will only look at elements. Here is a snippet that shows this behavior.

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {

   var parentNode = document.querySelector('.parentNode');
   var childNode  = parentNode.children[0].innerHTML;
   alert(childNode);

}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="button">Click To Check Node</button>
<div class = "parentNode">

  <div id = "i0">
   TEXT HERE
  </div>

  <div id = "i1">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much for a detailed explanation. You solved all my problems and I got my actual code to work now.

Comment: there's also the newer element.firstElementChild that does what firstChild should